# У него большие рыбьи глаза. Являются ли определения однородными?

Tags: синтаксис

У него большие рыбьи глаза. Являются ли определения однородными? "Рыбьи" явно имеет переносное значение - эпитет, но "большие" - значение прямое. Если "рыбьи" - это бессмысленные, то, как мне кажется, неоднородные. Но почему-то хочется произнести с паузой: большие, (какие-то) рыбьи глаза.

Comment: Ответ на ваш первый вопрос не был для вас полезным, не решил вашу проблему? Нет НИКАКОЙ реакции. У вас есть возможность принять ответ, оставить комментарий к ответу.

Comment: Здравствуйте. Я Вам очень благодарна, Ваш ответ был полезен.

Comment: Я не знаю, есть ли на сайте возможность каким-то образом поощрить того, кто помог решить проблему, ответив на заданный вопрос.

Comment: Лариса, это сделать очень просто. Кликнете по стрелочке на ответе, и тогда она станет зеленой. Это приемка ответа.  Можно еще проголосовать за ответ, нажав верхнюю стрелочку. Это максимальная благодарность отвечающему — 25 баллов.  Нам важна ваша оценка,  так как это еще и престижность сайта.  Наши участники будут охотно вам помогать, если вопросы того стоят и если вы к тому же вежливы и доброжелательны.

Comment: Можно не  принимать сразу ответ, а только проголосовать за него, если он в чем-то полезен.  То есть подождать другие ответы, если проблема оказалась до конца нерешенной. Потом вы  можете принять один из ответов.

Comment: Ваш вопрос достаточно интересен, возможно, на него будут ответы. Но если нет, то я сама отвечу позже.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Смотрим словарь на  **[Грамоте.ру](https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B9&mode=slovari&l=1&dicts%5B%5D=42):**

**Большой толковый словарь**

**РЫБИЙ,** -ья, -ье. 1. к Рыба (1 зн.). Р-ья чешуя. Р. хвост. Пальто на рыбьем меху (шутл.; без тёплой подкладки, холодное). Р. клей (из плавательного пузыря и чешуи). Р. жир (жидкий жир из печени тресковых рыб). **2. Бесстрастный, холодный.** Р-ья кровь. **Р-ьи глаза.**

Слово ***рыбий*** может быть **относительным** прилагательным (по сущ. рыба), а может иметь второе/качественное значение (бесстрастный, холодный). Хотя оно **переносное** (метафорическое), но уже указано в словаре, то есть вполне самостоятельное.  Другими словами, это уже не художественная метафора, а полноценное **качественное прилагательное**.

2. При сочетании с другими прилагательными чаще встречаются **неоднородные** отношения, то есть называются **разные** признаки.

(1)  *У него были **большие рыбьи** (= бесстрастные, холодные) глаза*.

Сравнить: *У него были **холодные, рыбьи** глаза* (разными словами называется один и тот же признак).

В то же время возможно **сближение** признаков по внешнему виду, по общему впечатлению, и тогда **возможен** вариант с запятой:

(2) *У него были **большие, рыбьи** глаза.*

3. У  **[Розенталя](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=98#pp98)** есть  пример по этой теме.

Определения однородны: 5) если представляют собой **художественные определения:** Одни кузнечики дружно трещат, и утомителен… этот непрестанный, кислый и сухой звук (Т.); Его бледно-голубые, стеклянные глаза разбегались (Т.); Старуха закрыла свинцовые, погасшие глаза (М. Г.); то же при употреблении определения-прилагательного в **переносном** значении: ***круглые, рыбьи*** глаза мальчика; тонкие, журавлиные ноги;

4. Тема сложная, много **авторских** решений. Чтобы не ошибиться, очень полезно работать с текстами, которые даны в  [Карте слов](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC/%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B1%D1%8C%D0%B8+%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0). Удивительно, как много прилагательных может использоваться совместно с сочетанием ***рыбьи глаза***:

*В **блёклых рыбьих** глазах плескалась смесь недоумения и растерянности. Он отчуждённо, холодно смотрел на них **водянистыми рыбьими** глазами. Придворные следопыты сидели, вперив в подчинённого докладчика **неподвижные рыбьи** глаза. Его **бледно-голубые рыбьи** глаза никогда не смотрели прямо и честно в лицо другим людям.– Что вам? – **равнодушные рыбьи** глаза продавщицы смотрят на меня.*